# How to check if there are errors / warning in the IEditorPart

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

Is it possible to check if [IEditorPart](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fui%2FIEditorPart.html) has errors / warnings programmatically?

Comment: What do you mean by 'has errors'? You can test if a file has problems associated with it, is that what you mean?

Comment: Yup - no error / warning markers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Errors, warnings, bookmarks etc. are represented by 'markers' which are attached to a resource.

The `IMarker` interface is used to describe these markers, you can get all the markers for a file using:

```java
IFile file = .... the file you want to look at

IMarker [] markers = file.findMarkers(null, true, IResource.DEPTH_INFINITE);
```

this gives you all types of marker. To just get problems use:

```
IMarker [] markers = file.findMarkers(IMarker.PROBLEM, true, IResource.DEPTH_INFINITE);
```